# Callback seems not to be executed when attached to another thread

Tags: python, multithreading, future, python-asyncio

What I want to do is, **in the Python console**:

1. Create an asyncio future
2. Attach a callback to this future
3. Set the future value (and so get at the same time the callback result)

To do this, I tried that, **in the Python console**:

```py
from threading import Thread
import asyncio

def start_loop(loop):
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_forever()

new_loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
t = Thread(target=start_loop, args=(new_loop,))
t.start()

fut = new_loop.create_future()
fut.add_done_callback(lambda _: print("Hey"))

fut.set_result(True)
```

I expect "Hey" to be printed, but actually I get nothing.

**Additional information:**

When I do:

```py
import asyncio

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

fut = loop.create_future()
fut.add_done_callback(lambda x: print("Hey"))

fut.set_result(True)

loop.run_forever()
```

I get the expected result, but I had to call `run_forever` while the future is already set.

**My questions are:**

1. Why my first block of code does not do the job as expected ?
2. Is there a hypothetical syntax like the following existing ?

```py
import asyncio

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

fut = loop.create_future()

# Hypothetical part
loop.run_forever_in_background()
# End of hypothetical part

fut.add_done_callback(lambda x: print("Hey"))

fut.set_result(True)
```

My high level purpose is to play with futures and asyncio directly **in the console**, to get a better understanding of it.

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention when playing with `asyncio` loops, futures etc. in multithreading context.

> Almost all `asyncio` objects are **not thread safe**, which is
>   typically not a problem unless there is code that works with them from
>   outside of a Task or a callback.
>   ...
>   To schedule a coroutine object from a different OS thread, the
>   `run_coroutine_threadsafe()` function should be used. It returns a
>   `concurrent.futures.Future` to access the result:

```
from threading import Thread
import asyncio

def start_loop(loop):
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_forever()

new_loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
t = Thread(target=start_loop, args=(new_loop,))
t.start()

async def add_future():
    fut = new_loop.create_future()
    fut.add_done_callback(lambda _: print("Hey"))
    fut.set_result(True)


asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(add_future(), loop=new_loop)
```

Test:

```
$ python3 test.py 
Hey
```

---

Another option is using [`loop.call_soon_threadsafe(callback, *args, context=None)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.call_soon_threadsafe).

https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html#asyncio-multithreading